Rerun Ionic scripts to retain styling and functions between Astro View Transition (Vanilla Javascript)
I've integrated Capacitor with Astro which overall works well. When I want to get more of a native look, I saw that the parent developer, Ionic, has Web Components that alter to the current device's look (ios or md - Material Design). However, using Astro's View Transitions, there seems to be some odd inconsistency with the styling. Most notably with the ion-header, the header will disappear between the transition as Astro does not rerun scripts explicitly. However, other functionality and styling for components such as ion-button are the same. I am trying to figure out how to manually initialize the Ionic script to retain the native styling of the page (either as 'ios' or 'md'). Using the Astro data-astro-rerun does not work as the warning says that it can't rerun external scripts. There are the event-handler directives such as astro:after-swap which is where I am trying to figure out how to call the overall Ionic script to re-apply classes to elements such as the html tag.
I use this CDN to load the script: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"
Link to Ionic CDN instructions
The current HTML layout is like this:
<html lang='en'>
    <Head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <link rel='icon' type='image/svg+xml' href='/favicon.svg' />
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover' />
        <meta name='generator' content={Astro.generator} />
        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta name='title' content={title} />
        <meta name='description' content={description} />
        <script type='module' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js' is:inline></script>
        <script nomodule src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js' is:inline></script>
        <ViewTransitions />
    </Head>

    <body>
        <ion-app>
            <NavBar title={title} />
            <ion-content class='ion-padding'>
                <slot />
            </ion-content>
        </ion-app>
    </body>
</html>

Navbar is simply laid out like this:
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>{title}</ion-title>
        {
            title !== "Homepage" && (
                <ion-buttons slot='end'>
                    <ion-button href='/'>Back</ion-button>
                </ion-buttons>
            )
        }
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

Before load:


After Load:



Ionic components do not support hydration. Also what is your question?

Is the hydration you're referring to in regards to Javascript functionality after the page loads or the CSS class shown in the photos? If the latter, the "hydration" class is only to toggle visibility. But the short question is how to keep the ion-header styling in between pages when View Transition is on. What I've noticed is that View Transition deletes all the nodes in the head element and specifically ion-header adds style tags in the head which then get deleted by View Transition.

Found a useful post that may point you in the right direction: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-ionic-angular-ssr-to-work-in-new-project/239741
